# HTTP POST not working.Getting Not Found error

Tags: java

I am trying to Post a .txt file to a local tomcat webserver that i have on my system.
But when i try to do a post then i get a Error: Not Found.
The source file is present but even after that i get this error.
Can you please let me know what i am doing wrong here. i have pasted my code below.

```
    File file = new File("C:\\xyz\\test.txt");    
    URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/process/files");    
    urlconnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();     
    urlconnection.setDoOutput(true);    
    urlconnection.setDoInput(true);
    urlconnection.setRequestMethod("POST"); 

    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(urlconnection.getOutputStream());
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    int i;     // read byte by byte until end of stream     
    while ((i = bis.read()) >0) {
        bos.write(i);     
        }
    bos.close();

    System.out.println(((HttpURLConnection)urlconnection).getResponseMessage());
    } catch(Exception ae)
    {
        ae.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        InputStream inputStream;
                int responseCode=((HttpURLConnection)urlconnection).getResponseCode();    
                if ((responseCode>= 200) &&(responseCode<=202) ) {
                    inputStream = ((HttpURLConnection)urlconnection).getInputStream();     
                    int j;     
                    while ((j = inputStream.read()) >0) {
                        System.out.println("------ TESTING ------");     
                        }     
                    } else {
                        inputStream = ((HttpURLConnection)urlconnection).getErrorStream();
                        }
                ((HttpURLConnection)urlconnection).disconnect();
            } catch (IOException e) {    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Can you please let me know what is going wrong here.
I am scratching my head on this for a long time now.

Thanks
Vikeng

Comment: You need to make a multipart post. You know there are libraries that do all that work you're doing manually, right? They would make this task significantly easier.

Answer (score 0):

The URL you are POSTing to needs to point to a servlet or something similar.  You cannot upload a file to a directory just by sending a POST request--the POST request has to be handled by something.

Comment: Thanks michael. yes you are right, the post request needs to be handled by a a servlet, jsp or similar. I was a bit confused as i was new to this HTTP PUT/POST concept i was told to do this on a remote server.